# Angular multiple image preview using fileReader using promise

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-promise, filereader

I am trying to return image src base64 with a method to preview multiple images. I am using fileReader inside a promise. I am not returning any value in it.
I am sending the value as a File object.
my code is as below.

Template

```
 <div *ngFor="let file of filelist">
   <img [src]="readFile(file) | async">
 </div>
```

TS

```
async readFile(file: File) {
    return new Promise(done => {
        debugger
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
             done(reader.result);
            };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    })
}
```

any help with this appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: I doubt you can set the `src` property to an array buffer. Try using a data url instead.

Comment: @Bergi I tried data url as well it also doesn’t work. I believe the function should return base64 string. That’s what doesn’t work.

Comment: A data url is a base64 string, isn't it? Can you show us what you tried and maybe the output of logging the reader result?

Comment: Alternatively, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30728883/1048572) appears to be a much simpler solution